# Parse JSON to TableView

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to parse my JSON response to my TableView. The problem is that I don't get any result in my TableView.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class MenuViewController: UITableViewController {

    var products: [Product] = []

    // MARK: View Controller Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Alamofire.request(.GET, Urls.menu).responseJSON { request in
            if let json = request.result.value {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
                    let data = JSON(json)
                    var product: [Product] = []

                    for (_, subJson): (String, JSON) in data {
                        product += [Product(id: subJson["id"].int!, name: subJson["name"].string!, description: subJson["description"].string!, price: subJson["price"].doubleValue)]
                    }

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.products += product
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.products.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    private struct Storyboard {
        static let CellReuseIdentifier = "Product"
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Storyboard.CellReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let product = self.products[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = product.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = product.description

        return cell
    }
```

I debugged my numberOfSectionsInTableView and I got this result:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
5
```

Five is the total of items in my JSON request, but my View is never updated. I was watching some classes about Swift, and in one of them, I see the teacher showing this method `self.tableView.reloadData()` but didn't work for me, or at least, I'm doing it wrong.

The rest of the code, I believe is correct, but without the reload of the data, I can't show it in my tableView.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.products.count
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've mixed up numberOfRowsInSection with numberOfSections. Return 1 for numberOfSections (or just delete that function entirely, it's optional) and products.count for numberOfRows.